# Improving the performance of a BinaryReader

Tags: c#, caching, binaryreader

I am currently in the process of writing a BinaryReader that caches the `BaseStream.Position` and `BaseStream.Length` properties.  Here is what I have so far:

```
public class FastBinaryReader
{
    BinaryReader reader;

    public long Length { get; private set; }
    public long Position { get; private set; }

    public FastBinaryReader(Stream stream)
    {
        reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        Length = stream.Length;
        Position = 0;
    }

    public void Seek(long newPosition)
    {
        reader.BaseStream.Position = newPosition;
        Position = newPosition;
    }

    public byte[] ReadBytes(int count)
    {
        if (Position + count >= Length)
            Position = Length;
        else
            Position += count;

        return reader.ReadBytes(count);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Instead of providing a `Length` and `Position` property, I would like to create a `BaseStream` property that allows me to expose my `Position` and `Length` properties as `FastBinaryReader.BaseStream.Position` and `FastBinaryReader.BaseStream.Length`, so that my existing code will stay compatible with the original `BinaryReader` class.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why don't you access these properties through `BinaryReader.BaseStream` in the first place? After all, if the stream doesn't support those then no amount of caching will make it work.

Comment: Maintaining my own Position and Length properties greatly improves the performance of the reader when checking for End of File.  In tests with 1000 byte reads the speed almost doubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do this exactly the way you have it here.

Consider that you need to expose a property of type `Stream` (what `BinaryReader.BaseStream` is). So you 'll need to create your own class deriving from `Stream`. This class would need to:

- take a reference to `FastBinaryReader` so that it can override `Stream.Length` and `Stream.Offset` by delegating to a `FastBinaryReader` member
- take a reference to a `Stream` (the same one passed in the `FastBinaryReader` constructor) in order to delegate all other operations to that stream (you could have these `throw new NotImplementedException()` instead, but you never know which library method is going to call them!)

You can imagine how it'd look:

```
private class StreamWrapper : Stream
{
    private readonly FastBinaryReader reader;

    private readonly Stream baseStream;

    public StreamWrapper(FastBinaryReader reader, Stream baseStream)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.baseStream = baseStream;
    }
    public override long Length
    {
        get { return reader.Length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return reader.Position; }
        set { reader.Position = value; }
    }

    // Override all other Stream virtuals as well
}
```

This would work, but it seems to me to be slightly clumsy. The logical continuation would be to put the caching in `StreamWrapper` instead of inside `FastBinaryReader` itself:

```
private class StreamWrapper : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream baseStream;

    public StreamWrapper(Stream baseStream)
    {
        this.baseStream = baseStream;
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { /* caching implementation */ }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { /* caching implementation */ }
        set { /* caching implementation */ }
    }

    // Override all other Stream virtuals as well
}
```

This would allow you to use `StreamWrapper` transparently and keep the caching behavior. But it raises the question: is the `Stream` you work with so dumb that it doesn't cache this by itself?

And if it isn't, maybe the performance gain you see is the result of that `if` statement inside `ReadBytes` and not of caching `Length` and `Position`?

Comment: `BaseStream.Position` and `BaseStream.Length` incur expensive calls to the OS (if you're using a `FileStream`), probably to allow safe concurrent access to the file via multiple streams. But I like your idea of patching the Stream class instead. +1

Comment: Then I 'd go with a caching `StreamWrapper` and use a stock `BinaryReader`, it feels much cleaner this way. Also, thanks for the heads up on stream performance.

Comment: I posted my implementation below.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the final implementation, if anyone is interested.  Passing this as a `Stream` object to a `BinaryReader`, instead of the usual `FileStream` object, yields about a 45% improvement in speed on my machine, when reading 1000 byte chunks.

Note that the Length param is only accurate when *reading*, since Length is read in at the start and doesn't change. If you are writing, it will not update as the length of the underlying stream changes.

```
public class FastFileStream : FileStream
{
    private long _position;
    private long _length;

    public FastFileStream(string path, FileMode fileMode) : base(path, fileMode)
    {
        _position = base.Position;
        _length = base.Length;
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return _length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set
        {
            base.Position = value;
            _position = value;
        }
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin seekOrigin)
    {
        switch (seekOrigin)
        {
            case SeekOrigin.Begin:
                _position = offset;
                break;
            case SeekOrigin.Current:
                _position += offset;
                break;
            case SeekOrigin.End:
                _position = Length + offset;
                break;
        }
        return base.Seek(offset, seekOrigin);
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count)
    {
        _position += count;
        return base.Read(array, offset, count);
    }

    public override int ReadByte()
    {
        _position += 1;
        return base.ReadByte();
    }
}
```